# Eclipse helios Servlet creation wizard fields are blank

Tags: servlets, eclipse-3.6, helios

Am trying to create a simple servlet using servlet creation wizard in helios(eclipse). A popup opens up and when I type the class-name, at the top of the popup I can view a red cross mark which says 'The Source folder cannot be empty'. There is Browse bttn available, so when I click and go there, a popup opens but do not allow me to select anything in it. Please help me in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating Servlets by wizard only work for projects of type *Dynamic Web Project*. Truncate your current project and recreate it using *New > Project > Web > Dynamic Web Project* wizard.

Comment: I have created dynamic web project only and not able to create servlet